# Saving a resized image on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, image, jupyter-notebook, saving-data

I'm very new to the world of coding and really struggling to figure out how to do this. I am currently running python 3 on Jupyter notebooks. I have managed to resize the images but I have no idea how to save the resized images onto either my desktop of the file in notebooks where the original sized images have come from.

I have not yet been able to find any additional ways to

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image (filename='img/imageone.jpg', width=200, height=200)
```